# ¿Como se actualiza registros con SqlAlchemy?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Python con Flask y SqlAlchemy, para esto las operaciones básicas que se realizan son la de crear un registro, modificarlo y eliminarlo. Para crear el registro con el siguiente fragmento de código

...

```
try:
    pp = Persona(ci=ci, ext=ext, primerAp=prap, segundoAp=seap, \
        nombres=nom, fecha_nacimiento=fnac) #instaciamos una clase

    pp.usuario = 'usario23'
    pp.fecha = datetime.now()
    pp.estado = 'V'

    db.session.add(pp)
    db.session.commit()

except(KeyError, TypeError, ValueError):
    raise jsonify(resultado='Error')
return jsonify(resultado='Ok', Persona=pp.aJson())
```

...

He buscado en documentación de SqlAlchemy y no encuentro la manera de actualizar una instancia de un objeto, algo asi como db.session.update(pp)
db.session.commit()

¿Alguien sabe somo se realiza?

Comment: Bienvenido Elvis, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask], tu pregunta es muy ambigua, necesitas contextualizar el problema. Comparte el código de lo que estás intentando (el mínimo necesario), explica el comportamiento esperado, y el comportamiento real, muestra las trazas y los mensajes de error, ayúdanos a ayudarte. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas es la forma de actualizar un registro, puedes hacerlo similar al `insert` así:

```
persona = Persona.query.get_or_404(id) #obtenemos el registro que queremos actulaizar por medio de su id
```

Posteriormente indicamos los datos a actualizar:

```
persona.usuario = 'nuevo_usuario' #Aquí se actualiza el dato en la columna usuario, tu puedes usar cualquier o cuantas columnas tengas
```

Por último agregamos los cambios a la base como siempre:

```
db.session.add(persona)
```

Existe otra forma con menos lineas:

```
#Dentro del dict puedes agregar todas las columnas del registro a actualizar
persona = Persona.query.filter_by(id=id).update(dict(usuario='nuevo_usuario'))

db.session.commit() #Guardamos los cambios con commit
```

Solo hay que tener cuidado ya que si en tu `filter_by` buscaste por algún otro campo y el valor de ese campo coincide en más de un registro, se van a actualizar todos en cuanto se aplique el *commit*.